# Error while using Ant with Google App Engine on Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ant, datanucleus

I have a Google App Engine application written in Java that I'm trying to get set up to work with the Travis continuous integration server. As part of this process, I need to automate the build using ant (previously, I had just been using Eclipse).

In Google's documentation for App Engine, they have a complete ant buildfile for an App Engine project:

```
<project>
  <property name="sdk.dir" location="../appengine-java-sdk" />

  <import file="${sdk.dir}/config/user/ant-macros.xml" />

  <path id="project.classpath">
    <pathelement path="war/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <fileset dir="war/WEB-INF/lib">
      <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${sdk.dir}/lib">
      <include name="shared/**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
  </path>

  <target name="copyjars"
      description="Copies the App Engine JARs to the WAR.">
    <copy
        todir="war/WEB-INF/lib"
        flatten="true">
      <fileset dir="${sdk.dir}/lib/user">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
      </fileset>
    </copy>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="copyjars"
      description="Compiles Java source and copies other source files to the WAR.">
    <mkdir dir="war/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <copy todir="war/WEB-INF/classes">
      <fileset dir="src">
        <exclude name="**/*.java" />
      </fileset>
    </copy>
    <javac
        srcdir="src"
        destdir="war/WEB-INF/classes"
        classpathref="project.classpath"
        debug="on" />
  </target>

  <target name="datanucleusenhance" depends="compile"
      description="Performs JDO enhancement on compiled data classes.">
    <enhance_war war="war" />
  </target>

  <target name="runserver" depends="datanucleusenhance"
      description="Starts the development server.">
    <dev_appserver war="war" />
  </target>

  <target name="update" depends="datanucleusenhance"
      description="Uploads the application to App Engine.">
    <appcfg action="update" war="war" />
  </target>

  <target name="update_indexes" depends="datanucleusenhance"
      description="Uploads just the datastore index configuration to App Engine.">
    <appcfg action="update_indexes" war="war" />
  </target>

  <target name="rollback" depends="datanucleusenhance"
      description="Rolls back an interrupted application update.">
    <appcfg action="rollback" war="war" />
  </target>

  <target name="request_logs"
      description="Downloads log data from App Engine for the application.">
    <appcfg action="request_logs" war="war">
      <options>
        <arg value="--num_days=5"/>
      </options>
      <args>
        <arg value="logs.txt"/>
      </args>
    </appcfg>
  </target>

</project>
```

I tried pasting this verbatum into the `build.xml` file for new app engine project generated using Eclipse, and running it (after copying the app engine sdk to the appropriate location, of course) but I'm getting the following error:

```
$ ant runserver
Buildfile: c:\Users\Ajedi32\Documents\Ajedi32\ant_test\build
xml

copyjars:
     [copy] Copying 7 files to c:\Users\Ajedi32\Documents\Ajedi32\ant_test\war\WEB-INF\lib

compile:
    [javac] c:\Users\Ajedi32\Documents\Ajedi32\ant_test\build.xml:39: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds

datanucleusenhance:
  [enhance] Encountered a problem: Unexpected exception
  [enhance] Please see the logs [C:\Users\Ajedi32\AppData\Local\Temp\enhance5135186886756266241.log] for further information.

BUILD FAILED
c:\Users\Ajedi32\Documents\Ajedi32\ant_test\build.xml:44: The following error occurred while executing this line:
c:\Users\Ajedi32\Documents\Ajedi32\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8\config\user\ant-macros.xml:95: Java returned: 1

Total time: 4 seconds
```

`C:\Users\Ajedi32\AppData\Local\Temp\enhance5135186886756266241.log` contains the following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected exception
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:76)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.<init>(Enhance.java:71)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.main(Enhance.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:74)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.<init>(Lorg/datanucleus/PersistenceConfiguration;Lorg/datanucleus/ClassLoaderResolver;)V
    at org.datanucleus.OMFContext.<init>(OMFContext.java:159)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.<init>(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:172)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.<init>(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:150)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1157)
    ... 7 more
```

What's gone wrong? Is Google's `build.xml` file wrong? I've literally never used ant before now, and I'm still pretty much a newbie with using Java and App Engine for production-quality applications so I'm totally lost here...

If anyone's ever set up App Engine to work with ant before, I'd really be interested in knowing how you did it. An example of an app engine application with a working ant build would be nice...

Comment: Oh yeah, and I already checked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554774/google-app-engine-jdo-enhancement-is-failing?rq=1

The guy there seemed to be having the same problem as me, but it doesn't seem like his problem ever actually got solved.

Comment: Try using [Gradle plugin](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/story/show/51319475). There is no excuse to use Ant in the end of 2013.

Comment: @musketyr I hope that's not why I got downvoted. :P

Comment: What has Ant got to do with anything here? You're simply using inconsistent jars, which is what NoSuchMethodError means. Suggest you go back and look at the datanucleus-XXX jars you have there and compare with what are consistent jars on the GAE and DataNucleus websites https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/Compatibility

Comment: So you're saying that Google's provided `build.xml` file *IS* wrong then? (The stuff in `${sdk.dir}/lib/shared/**/*.jar` is conflicting with the jars in `${sdk.dir}/lib/user/**/*.jar`?) As I said I have very little experience with app engine, so my ability to diagnose the problem is rather limited. My experience with ant is also basically non-existent, so I wanted to be sure I wasn't screwing something up on that front.