# Google AppEngine Enhancer: Encountered a problam: Unexpected exception

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, ant, intellij-idea

Possible duplicate of [Google App Engine JDO enhancement is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554774/google-app-engine-jdo-enhancement-is-failing).

This is my first app engine app which I'm implementing based on "appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8" and Intellij Idea 13.0. Following image shows my application.

[image]

I have designed my application based on tutorial on [Intellij Idea page](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Google+App+Engine). 
In `web.xml` file if I clear lines 8-18 and remove `mobilesoft.asia` package from src folder then application works fine and when I click on Run button then I can see my "Hello world" message that I have written on `index.jsp` file.

However, with having of my package and lines 8-18 in `web.xml` then exception happens when I click on Run button.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

==============

**Edit**: I downloaded 'datanucleus-appengine-2.0.0-final-dist' via [this page](https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/downloads/list). Seems it is latest release. Then I compared with what items I found under `appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8\lib\opt\tools\datanucleus\v2` and realized that seems appengine has newer version of datanucleus. Therefore, app engine shouldn't have problem with compile, I'm confused....

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I found the solution. I set 'Persistence' to "JPA 2" during creation of project. By set it to "JPA 1" problem solved (I don't know why) and I am able to compile the project.

So, select your project from Project panel. Then hit F4. Project structure opens. Select Google App Enfine from middle panel (under name of your project). Set Persistence to "JPA 1".

[image]